# plotting 3 columns from .dat file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot

I have a .dat file with 3 columns that I would like to plot.
How can I plot them using matplotlib/ python?  I am new to python, the .dat file was created using Fortran 90.  A portion of the filename.dat file is below

```
0.0 0.1 0.85
1.0 0.3 0.62
2.0 0.5 0.27
3.0 0.7 0.34
4.0 0.9 0.19
```

My python code (not correct) that plots the data in 3D is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

3Dplot.plot(*np.loadtxt("filename.dat",unpack=True), linewidth=2.0) #invalid syntax, why?
3Dplot.show()
```

What is the equivalent to the GNUplot command

```
splot 'filename.dat' using 1:2:3
```

in python? That is what I am trying to do.

However when I run the .py, I get "invalid syntax" error message which I am not sure why, but it is the line that starts with 3D.  How  can I plot 3d data?  I am able to do this if I have a .dat file with only two columns, but when I go to 3 dimensions I do not know what to do.  Thanks!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @efirvida just added it into the post since you asked, the error is "invalid syntax".  Thanks.

Comment: @Integrals: The reason for the SyntaxError is because identifiers (like `3Dplot`) [can not start with a digit](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: @unutbu Thanks, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the [Axes3D](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) object incorrectly, that's why you see a `SyntaxError`.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# Unpack file data.
dat_file = np.loadtxt("filename.dat", unpack=True)

# Plot data.
ax.scatter(*dat_file, linewidth=2.0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works really well!  Thanks a lot for pointing out why the invalid syntax error was coming up also.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add another .dat file to this code?  So I can plot two .dat files on the same figure?  Each .dat file has 3 columns, so I just meant putting 2 plots on the same figure. I tried many things but cannot figure it out.  In GNU plot, it is just 

    splot 'filename1.dat','filename2.dat'.  

So I tried many things like that here but couldn't figure it out. Thanks!  I will gladly post this as another question if you suggest.  Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Just read the new .dat file with another `dat_file2 = np.loadtxt()` line and then plot with a new `ax.scatter(*dat_file2)` line.

Comment: Well that worked quickly as well.  I failed to add another line for the ax.scatter plot,  I was trying to do everything with just 1 as in GNU.  Thanks a lot.